# CASE WHEN to choose which list of values to bring back ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use a case when to enforce some data access security that's not standard.

The basics of what I am trying to do keep causing the "more than one row" error.

I want to use 2 different subqueries with the result of the case when determining which list will be returned.

Example logic

```
SELECT CASE 

WHEN condition 1 is true THEN (SUBQUERY 1)
WHEN condition 2 is true THEN (SUBQUERY 2)
END AS ACCESS

FROM DUAL
```

Both subqueries on there own work fine and fetch back correct values, put them into the brackets above and it fails.

SUBQUERY 1

```
SELECT DISTINCT FND.PK1_START_VALUE 
FROM FND_GRANTS FG

JOIN FND_OBJECTS_VL FO
    ON FO.OBJECT_ID = FG.OBJECT_ID

JOIN FND_FORM_FUNCTIONS_VL FFF
    ON FO.OBJECT_ID = FFF.OBJECT_ID

JOIN FND_MENU_ENTRIES FME
    ON FME.MENU_ID  = FG.MENU_ID AND FFF.FUNCTION_ID = FME.FUNCTION_ID

LEFT JOIN FND_OBJECT_INSTANCE_SETS_VL FOIS
    ON FG.INSTANCE_SET_ID = FOIS.INSTANCE_SET_ID

JOIN FND_SESSION_ROLES FSR
    ON FG.ROLE_NAME  = FSR.ROLE_NAME

JOIN FND_SESSIONS FS
    ON FS.SESSION_ID = FSR.SESSION_ID

LEFT JOIN FND_FLEX_VALUES_VL FLV
ON FLV.DESCRIPTION = SUBSTR(FG.NAME, 1, CASE WHEN INSTR(FG.NAME,'Area')< 1 THEN INSTR(FG.NAME,'Cost')-2)
ELSE (INSTR(FG.NAME,'Area')-2)
END)

JOIN FND_TREE_NODE FND
    ON FLV.FLEX_VALUE = FND.PARENT_PK1_VALUE

WHERE FG.ROLE_NAME IN (:P_ROLE)----:P_ROLE is a list of VALUES fetching back the users system access.
AND FND.TREE_STRUCTURE_CODE = 'GL_ACCT_FLEX'
AND FND.TREE_CODE ='Cost Centre-T'
AND FND.DEPTH ='4'
ORDER BY FND.PK1_START_VALUE ASC)
```

SUBQUERY 2----idea here is the user has none of the roles in P_ROLE and therefore has all access to all sections

```
SELECT DISTINCT FND.PK1_START_VALUE
FROM FND_TREE_NODE FND

WHERE FND.TREE_STRUCTURE_CODE IN('GL_ACCT_FLEX')
AND FND.TREE_CODE IN('Cost Centre-T')
AND FND.DEPTH IN('4')
```

NOTE some sensitive data has been redacted from the query and replaced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (simple) option is to `UNION` them:

```
select columns 
  from subquery_1
  where condition = 1
union all
select columns 
  from subquery_2
  where condition = 2
```

Comment: this worked a treat much simper, sometimes its does not always have to be complicated i guess

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think you want `union all`:

```
SELECT q1.*
FROM (SUBQUERY 1) q1
WHERE condition1
UNION ALL
SELECT q2.*
FROM (SUBQUERY 2) q1
WHERE (NOT condition 1) AND  -- may not be necessary
      (condition 2) is true ;
```

Note:  This assumes that the column(s) returned by each subquery are compatible -- in both number and types.  The name in the result set is taken from the first subquery.

Comment: i knew it was something simple i just could not see it

Comment: @Leighholling . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept the first answer.

Comment: I did accept the first answer for simplicity, your soloution also gave the same result just a little less readable for some of my team

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below using CASE

```
        WITH sub1
         AS (SELECT ROWNUM rw,
                    data
             FROM   sub_query1),
         sub2
         AS (SELECT ROWNUM rw,
                    data
             FROM   sub_query2)
    SELECT CASE
             WHEN condition1 = 1 THEN a1.data
             WHEN condition1 = 2 THEN b1.data
             ELSE NULL
           END case1
    FROM   sub1 a1
           full outer join sub2 b1
                        ON a1.rw = b1.rw
```